# android send Dial Tone and detect end of input

Tags: android, phone-call, dtmf

I'm developing a little app which needs to start a simple call and send some DTMF tones.
By searching on the net i found that the correct way for doing it should be the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                  Uri.parse("tel://" + number + "," + dtmfTones));
```

Now, my problems are 2:

- I need to shut down the call after tones are sent.
- If possible I would like not to open the default dialer.

My app only needs to perform the call and send the tones, so the user has nothing to do nor interact with and that's why I don't need to open the dialer, it can also be done in background. Is there a way to do those things?

Thanks all and sorry for my not perfect english.

EDIT1: I tryed this method and I performed a call to another mobile number I have under control. The tones are sent and you can listen them without any problem.

EDIT2: i found also some apps which uses an unusual sequence of "#", ",", ".". but it is still not working, any idea?

I tryed to perform the same call to the house number which has to reply (it's a security system) but it doesn't recognize them. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @cdm unfortunatly no